# Python - Threading, Timing, or function use? 

Tags: java, python, multithreading, timing

I am having an issue formulating an idea on how to work this problem. Please help.

My project consists of an N x N grid with a series of blocks that are supposed to move in a random direction and random velocity within this grid (every .1 seconds, the location of the block is updated with the velocity). I have three "special" blocks that are expected to have individual movement functions. I will have other blocks (many of them) doing nothing but updating their location, and making sure they remain in the grid.

Now these three blocks have functions beyond movement, but each of these runs individually, waiting for the other block's special function to finish (block 2 will wait on block 1, Block 3 will wait on 2 and set it back to block 1, etc.) This queue of sorts will be running while the motion is happening. I want the motion to never stop. After each block's non-movement function runs n times, the code finishes.

My question is this: should I use threads to start and stop the non-movement functions, or is there a way to just set a time and set booleans that could use a class function after .1 seconds to continuously move the objects (and obviously loop over and over), and then use counts to end the program all together? If so, how would you write main function for this in Python? For all of this happening, does anyone think that Java would be significantly faster than Python in running this, especially if writing the data to a .txt file?

Comment: Do you want any sort of synchronization between the special functions and the movement, or (in other words) between the special functions and the world clock? Are the simulation steps supposed to happen in real time or simulated time?

Comment: The world time is what everything is based off of. The functions will actually be referring to locations at that current time, therefore, they will need to be synchronized with the time itself. Everything is directly related, and while the functions are happening the locations are constantly changing.

Comment: Also every one, that shouldn't be date, but data, sorry.

Comment: What about real vs simulated time?

Comment: I want a timer at 0, that starts at 0 and goes up. Every 10 seconds, One of the special boxes does its non movement function. First A, then A stops, then B, B stops, then C, then back to A. These special functions are all happening while the movement is happening and the special movement functions.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. Are 10 seconds of simulated time supposed to take 10 seconds of real time?

Comment: Sorry, 10 seconds of simulated time would take 10 seconds of real time in this code. Is there a way to do it otherwise, or do you think that it would work if I just set it up with  10 sec simulation time = 10 sec real time ?

Comment: How does that timing change the code?

Comment: If you don't need the program to run in real time, then it simplifies timing because it doesn't matter how much time the various tasks (movement, special functions) take. Another advantage is the simulation can run much faster than real time, so you may not have to wait as long for it to finish. You just run all the tasks for a given time, increment the world clock, then repeat. It's what's called "time step simulation" and looks like g.d.d.c.'s answer, but without the `sleep(0.1)` call. It sounds like you're envisioning the process to run in real time, but does it actually need to?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just need it set up so that it can produce the fastest results possible.

Comment: Does each special function run just when time ≡ 0 mod 10, or does each start at some time ≡ 0 mod 10 and run for 10 seconds, until the next one starts?

Comment: One will start running at 0, then run for 10 seconds, then the second one will run for 10 seconds, so on......Each function technically wont run for 10 seconds. I wanted the 10 seconds so that the program doesn't freeze. I just want to compute the fastest results possible in the long run.

Comment: Once you no longer tie the simulation clock to real time, you don't have to consider how long a function takes to run (which happens in real time, and won't affect simulation time). It sounds like you're still thinking of the functions running in real time. So do you want the special functions to run for 10 (simulated) seconds (which means they are run every tick for that period), or just when time ≡ 0 mod 10? The question needs a rewrite to state the exact requirements and [overall goal](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Comment: Also, did you not want more than one special function running at once because you were worried about processing everything in real time?

Comment: If possible, start thinking in terms of events. Block movement is an event. The special functions likely represent events. What are these events?

Comment: I'll explain each thing at a time.

Comment: I don't want all of them to fire at once, but then again as this is a simulation. SO technically this could work, my problem lies in the fact that I do not want a box being activated twice or while activated from another box being activated by another one, hence each special box should function independently,I can have the simulation run or days if needed. So after each function, I want to deactivate all boxes used (resetting the system) before the next box performs its simulation. That does not mean I want movement to stop. Movement is continuous. Hence, I wanted time between each special

Comment: event. I have used Python a lot, but I have not used the timing systems at all, and that is the only problem I am trying to wrap my head around. The problem is time wraps this all together. In the end, we probably need to use real time. My problem is I am just starting the psuedo code for this, so I dont know the true timing of the algorithm. I need this to handle though 3000 special functions. I will need the results fast, but I probably need for each test to run under 4 hours, because I'll have to run 3-9 tests. I really don't know how timing works in Python,but I am giving it a shot.

Comment: I just want ample time between each special function call so that no arguements will occur. If I can just have everything move in real time, I think it would be ok, even if I cut down the time between call to 3 seconds, that would be plenty of time for each function to do its stuff and would cut down the total test time for each test to be 2.5 hours. I feel for a bigger test, if I introduced 150 boxes into the system, this would slow the algorithm process down, especially if it is order n for a few parts of the special process.

Comment: So I feel real time, will probably be needed, Now that I have explained everything, it looks that def tick would be fine for the movement, but what do I do, set up time.time(), and then for while n being the amount of special functions is less the the total amount, run each method but set a return (as to pause the next function from going until the function before it is finished) for each function. Would that work? Then I don't have the use timings in the special functions, and the movements would truly be the only thing that needs the time.

Comment: Lets just say each special function has an order(n) , but a lof of functions inside that special function are order(n) as well.....

Comment: That still doesn't address my questions, and brings up new ones. For example, what's the `n` in the `O(n)` timing of the special functions? The same `n` in the grid size? The number of blocks? In any case, it doesn't matter with a times step simulation, as all the code happens instantaneously as far as simulation time is concerned. What really matters is determining when the special functions should run. At this point, I think a description of what the special functions actually do is in order.

Comment: Well, that stuff I am not authorized to give you, its too much information, and it is useless to even know what the special functions are. For this, it doesn't matter what is done, just that inside the special functions, functions will have the maximum of order n each. The question has already been answered, and I am starting to get very suspicious of why you need to know what the special functions sooo badly.

Comment: the special functions need to be running while the boxes are moving. They would be order n with n being the amount of things in a list.

Comment: What I need to know sooo badly is how to work the special functions into the world model. The purpose of the special functions is relevant in that they model some aspect of the system being simulated, which affects such things as when they are run, what events they are associated with &c. I had avoided asking about what the special functions did because I had hoped it wouldn't matter, but the description you've given so far is too vague to model properly as a simulation.

Comment: ... Saying `n` is the number of items in a list is meaningless as you don't say what list you're talking about. The variables in complexity notation must relate to function arguments. As you haven't described the functions in that great detail, describing the timing in terms of simulation objects (so far, the grid and blocks) would be acceptable. Note also that the complexity equation of a function is a completely describes the limiting behavior of the function; it includes the complexity of any functions it may call, thus subfunction complexities don't need to be mentioned.

Comment: All they do is make calculations dependent on others location and velocity. While the functions are happening, the locations and velocities change, and thats what I want. For instance if I called the x coord at one moment and the xcoord at another, they would be different and that is ok. Saying this, it didn't REALLY MATTER what the special function did, they need data from the boxes moving ALL THE TIME. I still don't see how now having this information changes how it works overall. I just want the boxes moving, and with the boxes moving having the functions deal with constantly changing info!

Comment: ... As for the functions needing to run while the blocks are moving, this is a given in a simulation. At each step, every function that runs runs simultaneously and instantaneously as far as the simulated world is concerned (though in the real world they take time and may run serially). Even though this particular question is answered, consider reading a good book on [simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918799/good-modelling-simulation-book-recommendations-for-programmers) to clear up the confusion.

Comment: I'm fine, then what were we arguing about?  I haven't taken Modeling and Simulation as a class, but I will be in the near future. I am not writing simulators all my life, but I have a very very limited time to crank this code out, hence the question, I only wanted that portion written for me. Now that I have that, the code was finished. Thankls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to handle all of them at once in a single update function rather than attempting to use Threads.  This is primarily because the Global Interpreter Lock will prevent multiple threads from processing concurrently anyway.  What you're after then is something like this:

```
def tick():
  for box in randomBoxes:
    box.relocate()

  specialBlock1.relocate()

  specialBlock2.relocate()

  specialBlock3.relocate()
```

Then we define a second function that will run our first function indefinitely:

```
def worker():
  while True:
    tick()

    sleep(0.1)
```

Now that we have an interval or sorts, we'll launch a Thread that runs in the background and handles our display updates.

```
from threading import Thread

t = Thread(target = worker, name = "Grid Worker")

t.daemon = True # Useful when this thread is not the main thread.

t.start()
```

In our `tick()` function we've worked in the requirements that specialBlocks 1, 2, and 3 are working in a set order.  The other boxes each take their actions regardless of what the others do.

Comment: Hmm I like it. How exactly would you write a thread for this? would def tick be its own method? So, I would start the timer,have a while loop to stop the entire process, call tick() (I dont have to be every .1 seconds, I didn't know python could constantly update in realtime), then just write my main function? If you could write an example thread, it would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TheChes44 - No worries, and happy to help.  I've added some additional code to demonstrate how to use the thread to move the while loop into the background.  I use this approach a lot to monitor things - "Check on this service's status on an interval and make sure it's online, if it's not, notify someone."

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Now what about the non-movement functions, where does that fit into the equation?

Comment: The better question is, can I just put the main function under it now? Also, is this the proper formatting for Python 3.2? that is the version I am going to write it in.

Comment: @TheChes44 - To be honest I'm not certain if it's close to proper syntax in 3.2.  It's fully functional in 2.7, which is what I've been using recently, but I haven't reviewed any changes to the threading module in 3.2.  The majority of the code is generic enough that it should be fine.

Comment: Hrmmm. Ok well If I run into issues in coding this for 3.2, I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Wanted to let you know your code worked perfectly, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you put the calls to the special functions together in a single function, you get [coordination](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/docs/EDA.pdf) ([2](http://Continuation,%20Coordination%20and%20Context)) for free.

```
def run(n, blocks):
    for i in range(n):
        for b in blocks:
            b.special()
```

As for the speed of Python versus Java, it depends on many things, such as the exact implementation. There is too little information to say.

Comment: would it iterate? I guess that would work, but what about the synchronous movement while all of this is happening? I mean, the most I would be doing is accessing through a list at a given time. So the time complexity would be linear at most. My concern is if I have 150 dummy blocks, and 3 special blocks, updating movement, acessing data and writing it to a file at the same time would it overload python, or would I see a significant different in the timing using Java instead?